# Socket programming in c language can not work remote

Tags: c, sockets, winsock

Im trying to write an online chess game in c language.

I've tried it with 127.0.0.1 and it works.The communication is done respectively like a chess game thats why i wrote the code like this.

The problem is when i tried to run the client program in an another computer (in this case the ip is my computer's ip.) it didnt work. I've deactivated the firewall but it didnt solve.Im sure it is working in local.

This is my server.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library
#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 312   //The port on which to listen for incoming data         
int main(){
SOCKET s;
struct sockaddr_in server, si_other;
int slen , recv_len;
char buf[BUFLEN];
WSADATA wsa;
slen = sizeof(si_other) ;
//Initialise winsock
printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0){
    printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("Initialised.\n");

//Create a socket
if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET){
    printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
}
printf("Socket created.\n");
//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons( PORT );
//Bind
if( bind(s ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
    printf("Bind failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
puts("Bind done");
char message[500];
//keep listening for data
char msg[50];
int order=0;
while(1){
    memset(buf,'\0', BUFLEN);
    memset(msg,'\0',50);
    printf("Waiting for data...");
    fflush(stdout);
     if(order==1){
        gets(msg);
        sendto(s, msg, 20,0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, slen);           
     }
     if( recvfrom(s, buf, 20, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen) &&       
     order==0){
        puts(buf);
        order=1;
     }
    printf("Received packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr),
    ntohs(si_other.sin_port));
    printf("Data: %s\n" , buf);
}
closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();
return 0;
}
```

and client.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library
#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"  //ip address of udp server
#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 312  //The port on which to listen for incoming data

int main(void){
struct sockaddr_in si_other;
int s, slen=sizeof(si_other);
char buf[BUFLEN];
char message[BUFLEN];
WSADATA wsa;
//Initialise winsock
printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0){
    printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("Initialised.\n");
//create socket
if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
    printf("socket() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
//setup address structure
memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(SERVER);
int order=1;
//start communication
while(1){
    printf("Enter message : ");
    gets(message);
    //send the message
    if (sendto(s, message,20 , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen) 
    && order==1){
       order=0;
    }
   if(recvfrom(s, buf, 20, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen) && 
   order==0){
        order=1;
        puts(buf);
    }
    memset(buf,'\0', BUFLEN);
    puts(buf);
}
closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are your *server* running? I don't know how it works on Windows, but ports less than `1024` are *privileged* and usually requires the programs that bind to them to be run as a super or administrator user.

Comment: In the fifth line in client.c, change the SERVER ip address from 127.0.0.1 to the ip address of the server. 127.0.0.1 will only work if the client and the server are on the same machine.

Comment: @ThePrenx yes in this case server is my own computer and client is my friend's computer. I change the server ip with my ip where i learned from whatismyip.com.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude server is my own computer and the client is my friend's computer. So server is running :)

Comment: Also, you do know that UPD is *unreliable*? Each network the packets travels over increases the chances of it getting out of order or even being lost.

Comment: @AliBeratÇetin If your friend's computer is in the same network then the ip given off by whatismyip.com won't work as that is the external IP. You need to find local (internal) ip address of your friend's interface (should be something like 192.168.*.* or 10.*.*.*). IF your friend's PC is somewhere outside your local network (like in the internet) then you will have to forward the tcp or udp port on your router where your server application is running. Search for Network address translation and port forwarding on google for more details.

Comment: You have to use an ip address that is reachable by the other computer. 127.0.0.1 always refers to the local computer. On a lan you can replace the ip address for the ip assigned by the router. Also you may have to establish firewall rules on both sides. And if you want to do this over the internet you will have to establish forwarding rules in the router. You need some network background for this.

Comment: Step 1)  Can you ping the server from the client?

Comment: @MartinJames with the external ip which is like 172.12.333.12(i randomed) i can not ping.It says request timed out.

Comment: @ThePrenx yes were in the same wireless network. Ive tried it.I get it from ipconfig command in cmd and the ipv4 adress is 192.168.1.XX.It didnt work too.

Comment: Sounds firewally to me, or AV,. if you cannot ping 192.168.1.XX from the local net.

Comment: @Juan yes i tried port routing with my modem interface but as you said were in the same network and i need the ip assigned by the router. Its like 192.168.xx.yy.

Comment: It is solved now with the router ip. The AV is the blocker but it didnt say anything about this.Thanks for all help.

Comment: @ThePrenx which port should i direct with my router interface? Is it the port which i used in the program? In this program i used port number 312, should the router direct the connections to the 312 port number?

Comment: @AliBeratÇetin For accessing your server from outside your local network, you can forward a particular port to the internal ip:port. E.g. say you want to access the server from outside on port 5555, you map external port 5555 to internal IP:312 in your router. Thus whenever you access your externalIP:5555 your router will redirect your packet to internalIP:312. The outside port and inside port can be the same (312)

Comment: @The Prenx thanks for excellent answer.